# "This was the finish of their lives"

Tags: word-usage

> This was the finish of their lives

I recently read this sentence and it appeared as odd to me.

For me, *finish* as a noun is closely related to races, as in *finish line*. In that context, it furthermore carries a sense of *goal*. I think that wouldn't be appropriate if someone's life is terminated. I think *end of their lives* would be more appropriate.

What is your opinion?

Comment: What makes you think this is about someone's life being terminated?

Comment: More context and saying if the author was the native English speaker would help.

Comment: More context needed. Unless a phrase is a well-known idiom, they are only recognisable and understandable in context.

Comment: Definitely need more context. For example, if this was about them being in an actual race, one in which they showed a very extreme effort at the end of the race, that might be the (best) finish of their lives. Or something might have made their lives shine out dramatically, thus providing the finish (on the face of) their lives. And so on.

Comment: Or they might have tasted a beer, wine, gin, etc, which lingered very nicely in the mouth.

Comment: I meant "life is terminated" as a general paraphrase for "to die". Sorry if that isn't appropriate.
There is not much more context. It is not from a text. It is actually an example sentence for the noun "finish" from an English learning resource.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to focus on specific "unusual" contexts such as *when someone's life is terminated*. All you need to know is that we [almost always](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20end%20of%20the%2Cthe%20finish%20of%20the&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cthe%20end%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cthe%20finish%20of%20the%3B%2Cc0) use ***end*** rather than ***finish*** to refer to the final part of any time-span, sequence of actions, etc...

[image]

It may be worth noting that the most common words in the relatively uncommon sequence *the finish of the XXXX* are [***race, stroke, work, first, surface.***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=the%20finish%20of%20the%20*&year_start=1800&year_end=2008&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t2%3B%2Cthe%20finish%20of%20the%20%2A%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20stroke%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20race%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20first%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20whole%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20surface%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20verses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20last%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20picture%3B%2Cc0#t2%3B%2Cthe%20finish%20of%20the%20*%3B%2Cc0%3B%2Cs0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20stroke%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20work%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20race%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20first%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20whole%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20surface%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20verses%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20last%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20war%3B%2Cc0%3B%3Bthe%20finish%20of%20the%20picture%3B%2Cc0) I think it's significant that the fifth most common sequence *(the finish of the **surface**)* is a significantly different sense - referring to the final coat of varnish / glaze / etc. on some treated / layered surface, or perhaps the ***appearance*** of that surface after polishing or sanding smooth (or even just the ***feel*** of, say, fabric after ironing with spray starch).

---

TL;DR: Stick to *the **end** of XXXX*. Forget about ever using ***finish*** in such contexts.